# Morphism of discrete quantum groups

Tags: c-star-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, pontrjagin-duality

In the paper [Kazhdan's Property T for Discrete Quantum Groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.0665.pdf)
, we read the following fragment:

[image]

First, note that I think there is a typo and that codomain and domain of the dual maps have to be interchanged.

How exactly, starting from a morphism of discrete quantum groups $\hat{\pi}: \hat{\mathbb{G}}\to \hat{\mathbb{H}}$, do we construct a morphism of compact quantum groups $\pi: \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{G}$? I guess some form of Pontryagin duality might be relevant. A reference or a proof sketch is appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!